# What is a "compression stop" for a tongue & groove joint?

Tags: mechanical-engineering

I came across this snippet in a vendor manual for gaskets for a flanged joint for vacuum duty (tongue & groove). What exactly is a compression stop? Is it evident in the sketch below?

http://www.flexitallic-gmbh.eu/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/Gasket_Design_Criteria.pdf

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please show the type of gasket under consideration (spiral wound metal-fiber, p31). It makes it a lot easier to understand the importance of compression stop in this application.

Answer (score 1):

A compression stop is a method of preventing the gap between the two pieces being zero ie providing a minimum space for the gasket. This could be achieved by the two “teeth” or annular ring being slightly longer than the cutout or groove they go in.

Comment: In these flanges, the gasket goes in the groove, so the bossed ring needs to be shallower than the groove. The stops could be bosses or pins near the bolt holes or compression tubes inside the bolt holes.